# Can't add animation delay to element

Tags: jquery, css, animation, delay

i want to start start at a random keyframe of a css3 animation.
With a negative animation-delay it is possible to change the start point.
so my idea is to do something like this:

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * -100) - 1;
console.log(random);
$("#colorDiv").css({
 '-webkit-animation-delay': random + 's'
});
```

The problem only this is added to the element:

```
style="-webkit-animation: -25s;
```

so the -delay is missing.
The CSS Animation locks like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes coloursBG {
  0% {background-color: #39f;}
 15% {background-color: #8bc5d1;}
 30% {background-color: #f8cb4a;}
 45% {background-color: #95b850;}
 60% {background-color: #944893;}
 75% {background-color: #c71f00;}
 90% {background-color: #bdb280;}
100% {background-color: #39f;}
}
#colorDiv{
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-duration: 50s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-name: coloursBG;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use this

```
 -webkit-animation-delay: 2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-delay: 25s;
```

Instead of `-webkit-animation: -25s;`

you can change the property here: [Example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation-delay)

Comment: i know but it is not possible to set it from Javascript for me.